# extract rows of data from a bunch of csv files that match specific dates mentioned in one column

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime

I have 61 csv file that are related to 61 days of the year but in each file there is not just the data of that date, there are also data corresponding to other of 61 days. The form of data is

```
4d7cc82e33d042fdf13b9149bcdacee1;2015-03-01 05:21.:52;45.631616;9.2073;20;0
4d7cc82e33d042fdf13b9149bcdacee1;2015-03-01 05:22:51;45.6316;9.2073;20;0
4d7cc82e33d042fdf13b9149bcdacee1;2015-03-01 05:23:51;45.6316;9.207333;20;0
4d7cc82e33d042fdf13b9149bcdacee1;2015-03-01 05:24:51;45.6316;9.207333;20;0
6b1d2f4037aa849e4f8274b61e6cb002;2015-02-28 23:37:47;45.30044;8.85833;20;49
6b1d2f4037aa849e4f8274b61e6cb002;2015-02-28 23:37:49;45.30035;8.85797;20;53
6b1d2f4037aa849e4f8274b61e6cb002;2015-02-28 23:37:51;45.30026;8.85758;20;57
6b1d2f4037aa849e4f8274b61e6cb002;2015-02-28 23:37:53;45.30017;8.85717;20;60
6b1d2f4037aa849e4f8274b61e6cb002;2015-02-28 23:37:55;45.30006;8.85674;20;64
```

for example in the second column as you see the date and time is reported a group of rows are related to 2015-03-01 and a group of rows are related to 2015-02-28
I want to read these 61 files and extract the rows that are related to each day and write them in other files for each day and obtain file that each one just has information for one day.
Do I have to concatenate all files in one dataframe to this job or not. till now I have tried:

```
data_path = " ... "
fp = glob.glob(os.path.join(data_path, "output_*")
for j in fp:
    df = pd.read_csv(j, sep=";",header=None,names = 
['trip','dateandtime','lat','lon','vehicle','velocity'])
    df = pd.to_csv(Path2, sep=" ",header = None, names = 
['trip',df.loc[df['dateandtime'] == '2015-03-01 
*','lat','lon','vehicle','velocity'])
```

But it seems nonsense. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import glob

data_path = '/my/data/'
columns = ['trip', 'dateandtime', 'lat', 'lon', 'vehicle', 'velocity']
df_all = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

for csv_filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(data_path, "output_*.csv")):
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_filename, sep=';', header=None, names=columns, parse_dates=['dateandtime'])
    df_all = df_all.append(df)

df_all.sort_values('dateandtime', inplace=True)

for key, group in df_all.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='dateandtime', freq='1D')):
    if not group.empty:
        csv_name = key.strftime('%Y-%m-%d.csv')
        group.to_csv(csv_name, sep=';', index=False)
```

It reads all the possible CSV files into a single dataframe, sorts them by date and then writes them out in groups. The name of the CSV file is the date.

Comment: evansHi, Thank You very much for your reply. I tried the code that you wrote and I ran it, it does not give me any error but the files are not written, it is some minutes the program is running but still files do not appear

Comment: Each of these 61 file has 2 to 3 millions of rows of data. Do you think it can be related to this issue?

Comment: Probably too much to all be held in memory at once. I suggest you at least test it on say 5 files first.

Comment: Ah ok, I will check to see what happens!

Comment: TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Float64Index'

Comment: Which version of Pandas and Python are you using?

Comment: Python 3.5.2 (default, Sep 14 2017, 22:51:06) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux

Comment: I don't know the version of pandas but I have installed it yesterday, I am gonna check

Comment: my pandas version is '0.21.0'

Comment: I have tested on the same versions (albeit Windows) based on two files using your sample data. I get that error only if `, index_col='dateandtime')` is uncommented from the `read_csv()` line, i.e. you should not add it.